# Ошибка при выполнении SQL запроса к базе данных 'Cats bd': foreign key mismatch - "owners" referencing "cats"

Tags: sql, sqlite, foreign-key

Вот при таком коде ошибка из заголовка при попытке выполнить последний запрос:

```
CREATE TABLE cats( id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
                   Name TEXT, 
                   ownerID INTEGER, 
                   specie TEXT, 
                   birthday DATE);

CREATE TABLE owners( OwnerID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
                     OwnerName TEXT, ownerSurname TEXT,
                     FOREIGN KEY (OwnerID) REFERENCES cats (OwnerID) );  

INSERT INTO cats( Name, ownerID, specie,  birthday) VALUES 
("Pushock", 1, "Scottish", 20-07-02 ), 
("Barsic", 2, "Siberian", 15-04-12), 
("Pascal", 2, "Siberian", 18-02-11),
("Floppa", 2, "Caracal", 2017-12-21);

INSERT INTO owners( OwnerName, ownerSurname)  VALUES  
("Vasiliy", "Kotov"), 
("Ivan", "Progerov");
```

Типы данных в обеих таблицах, вроде, совпадают. Как нормально связать эти две таблицы по ключам, чтобы не возникало такой ошибки?

Comment: Неправильное направление связи. Это у хозяина может быть два кота, а не у кота двое хозяев.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> CREATE TABLE owners ( OwnerID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
>                       OwnerName TEXT, 
>                       OwnerSurname TEXT );
>
> CREATE TABLE cats ( id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
>                     Name TEXT, 
>                     ownerID INTEGER, 
>                     specie TEXT, 
>                     birthday DATE,
>                     FOREIGN KEY (OwnerID) REFERENCES owners (OwnerID));
>
> INSERT INTO owners( OwnerName, ownerSurname)  
> VALUES  
> ("Vasiliy", "Kotov"), 
> ("Ivan", "Progerov");
>
> INSERT INTO cats( Name, ownerID, specie,  birthday)  
> SELECT "Pushock", OwnerID, "Scottish", '2020-07-02'
> FROM owners
> WHERE (OwnerName, ownerSurname) = ("Vasiliy", "Kotov");
>
> INSERT INTO cats( Name, ownerID, specie,  birthday)  
> SELECT Name, ownerID, specie,  birthday
> FROM ( SELECT "Barsic" Name, "Siberian" specie, '2015-04-12' birthday UNION ALL
>        SELECT "Pascal", "Siberian", '2018-02-11' UNION ALL
>        SELECT "Floppa", "Caracal", '2017-12-21' ) cats 
> CROSS JOIN ( SELECT OwnerID
>              FROM owners
>              WHERE (OwnerName, ownerSurname) = ("Ivan", "Progerov")) owners;
>
> SELECT *
> FROM owners 
> JOIN cats USING (ownerID);
> ```
>
> | OwnerID | OwnerName | OwnerSurname | id | Name | specie | birthday |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | Vasiliy | Kotov | 1 | Pushock | Scottish | 2020-07-02 |
> | 2 | Ivan | Progerov | 2 | Barsic | Siberian | 2015-04-12 |
> | 2 | Ivan | Progerov | 3 | Pascal | Siberian | 2018-02-11 |
> | 2 | Ivan | Progerov | 4 | Floppa | Caracal | 2017-12-21 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=a8ef0e65f60ff17b67917c0d53153125)*